# Use Selenium to access specific page on website

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

My research project requires me to download patent data from [this website](http://epub.sipo.gov.cn).

I have to enter a date, say, `2009.4.30`, and it returns a list of patent information. Only 3 entries are returned per page and I want to download all of them, so I need to scroll down.

Now I am trying to use Selenium to do scroll by using XPath to locate the *turn to* area and using the following to submit the page number request and turn to next page. It failed. I also have to try to `send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`. How do I get the extra data from the page?

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# download data from 
time1 = time.time()


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://epub.sipo.gov.cn/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("soso_text")
a = date(2009,5,30)
b = date(2009,6,9)

print "hello"
for dt in rrule(DAILY, dtstart = a, until = b):
print dt.year
print dt.month
print dt.day

date = str(dt.year) + "." + str(dt.month) + "." + str(dt.day)
filename = date+".txt"
f = open("/Users/jasondou/Google Drive/data/patent/" + filename, "wb")

driver.get("http://epub.sipo.gov.cn/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("soso_text")

elem.send_keys(str(date))
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')

for uchar in content:
    f.write(bytearray([ord(uchar)]))
print "hello here"
nextpage = driver.
find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/a[7]")
turnto = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/span")
print "hello 0"
print nextpage.get_attribute("innerHTML")
totalnum = int(nextpage.get_attribute("innerHTML"))

for i in range(2, totalnum + 1):
    print "i: "
    print i
    turnto =  driver.find_element_by_xpath
    ("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/span")
    turnto.send_keys(str(i))
    turnto.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
    for uchar in content:
        f.write(bytearray([ord(uchar)]))
    print "hello2"

 f.close()


time2 = time.time()
print time2-time1
```

Comment: How have you failed?

Comment: Don't forget to check the website disclaimer and copyright statement. Also, have you asked the webmaster for API access? May help you out.

Comment: thanks, the simple thing is that the turnto.send_key() did not work, not successfully click the page....

Comment: Bob, so you mean use webmaster instead of Selenium?